# Xcode Custom Project Template

Tags: ios, xcode, templates, project

I have a problem, I created a custom Xcode project template with a number of features.

The problem is that all my options don't fit in the window (cf.
 [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krMWI.png))

How do I fix this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Wow, is this bad UX... Xcode could really improve.